# Renaming files within a ton of subfolders

Tags: powershell, rename

I have the following code but it is renaming folders and files. When i use basename it says the file i get an error that says the Source and destination path must be different.

I want to rename sd^fks.pdf to sd_fks.pdf

```
Get-ChildItem $dstpath -Recurse | `
Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^'} | `
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^','_' }
```

Comment: `^` has [special meaning in regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#start-of-string-or-line-).  Try escaping it as `\^`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the circumflex character. Stick to the `Name` attribute. You might want to add `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` to only get files:

```
Get-ChildItem $dstpath -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '\^'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\^','_'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Where-Object` clause for this. Instead use `Filter` which makes the code run faster aswell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dstpath -Filter '*^*' -Recurse -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\^','_' }
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, regex escape:

```
[regex]::escape('^')

\^
```

'^' means 'the beginning of the line in regex:

```
'hi' -replace '^','prefix-'

prefix-hi
```

Or plug the expression in at https://regex101.com and see what it says.